# How to operate command prompt using c#?

Tags: python, c#, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I've created a "hello.py" file and placed it in the same directory as my c# .exe
and I run this on the command prompt via c#
and this is my progress so far

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
namespace c_hash_testing 
{
    class Primary
    {
        static void run()
        {
            Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.Start();

            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("python hello.py");
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        }
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            run();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

but when i run it
the output comes out to be

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.685]
> (c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\ ... \Debug>python hello.py 
> hello world
>
> C:\ ... \Debug>

But i specifically need the "hello world" part
so is there any way to read only the executed part because I don't want to sort the string out every time I run something else,
also is there any possible way that I could input into the cmd via c#?
for example if i made a calc.py
which inputs 2 numbers and then prints their sum?
**NOTE**
My aim is not to integrate python and c#, I just took .py as an example
 so please provide a solution that is applicable to .exe or any command prompt executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting

```
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c python hello.py"
```

instead of passing your command using StandardInput.

This is equivalent to typing

```
cmd /c python hello.py
```

at a command prompt, instead of typing:

```
cmd
```

followed by

```
python hello.py
```

Comment: If you take a look at the `cmd` options, `cmd /?`, you should see that there are others too. Of those, I would strongly advise, _unless you have a specific reason not to_, that you always include at least its `/D` option. Also the filename should ideally be `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe")`, instead of `"cmd.exe"`, to prevent reliance on the often broken or poorly modified `%Path%` environment variables. For the same reason, and to also prevent reliance upon the `%PATHEXT%` environment variable, `python` should be for example, `C:\Python38\python.exe`

Comment: thanks it works now, but could u elaborate what you meant by "instead of passing your command using StandardInput."?

Comment: @WiredDifferently - if you use `cmd /c`, then, as you can see from `cmd /?` help, it `Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates`.  Therefore, you don't need to provide the command to execute via `cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine`: in fact you can delete the three lines in your sample that begin with `cmd.StandardInput`.